# CountUp.js: not starting to count up

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

I tried to use countup.js - I used it several times in the past, but now it is not working anymore. Does anybody see the mistake?

HTML:

```
<div id="counter">1000</div>
```

JS:

```
  function countup() {
    var options = {
      useEasing: true,
      useGrouping: true,
      separator: '.',
      decimal: ',',
      suffix: 'People'
    };

    var demo = new CountUp('counter', 0, $("#counter").text(), 2, 4, options);
    if (!demo.error) {
      demo.start();
    } else {
      console.error(demo.error);
    }
  }

countup();
```

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PrGvvK

Comment: Check the console in your Codepen, there's several issues

Comment: Also, your not actually successfully importing the CountUp library...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Unfortunalety I have no idea how to solve these problems.

Comment: @Alicia what is wrong? I added them via external scripts?

Answer (score 3):

add countUp.js in your Code:

```
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/countup.js/1.8.2/countUp.min.js'></script>
```

[Working Demo](https://codepen.io/ghoul007/pen/zVKVaq)

Comment: It worked - but I included in via external scripts. Why do I have to include it like this?

Comment: @MaximilianNeuse, you  need to included in via external script, i put here just i  want to show you the problem.

Comment: This works, because it uses an older release - you can also change your external scripts to 1.8.2

Answer (score 3):

In your codepen example you are using version 2.0.4 (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/countup.js/2.0.4/countUp.min.js) which uses `ES6` code. You can see the error message in console.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

browsers doesn't have full ES6 support. So if you use version `1.8.2` which doesn't use ES6 code it will work via external script.

Below is the codepen using older version

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dBpxbd